# 14.04 LTS intermittently fails to resume from hibernation

Tags: 14.04, hibernate

Since upgrading to 14.04 LTS (64-bit), my PC will sometimes fail to resume from hibernation (perhaps one time in ten). Symptoms are that it attempts to resume, finds the suspended memory image, and shows the percentage of the image loaded (10%, 20%, etc.) It reaches 100% and then the PC reboots back to the BIOS splash screen. When the GRUB menu reappears, it does not have the usual timeout. I don't know what to try to isolate the cause.

Hibernation worked reliably on the same hardware under 12.04 LTS.